# Fatal error c1083 "afxwin.h"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I apologize for posting this question,
When I compile, I get an error

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file : 'afxwin.h' : No such file or directory
```

Thanks very much if you can give a hand.

code:

```
#if !defined(AFX_STDAFX_H__39403C06_D7D2_4132_9BC8_80C5C886FB8B__INCLUDED_)
#define AFX_STDAFX_H__39403C06_D7D2_4132_9BC8_80C5C886FB8B__INCLUDED_

#if _MSC_VER > 1000
#pragma once
#endif // _MSC_VER > 1000

#define VC_EXTRALEAN        // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers

#include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components
#include <afxext.h>         // MFC extensions
#include <afxdisp.h>        // MFC Automation classes
#include <afxdtctl.h>       // MFC support for Internet Explorer 4 Common Controls
#ifndef _AFX_NO_AFXCMN_SUPPORT
#include <afxcmn.h>         // MFC support for Windows Common Controls
#endif // _AFX_NO_AFXCMN_SUPPORT

#include <afxsock.h>        // MFC socket extensions

//{{AFX_INSERT_LOCATION}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ will insert additional declarations immediately before the previous line.

#endif // !defined(AFX_STDAFX_H__39403C06_D7D2_4132_9BC8_80C5C886FB8B__INCLUDED_)
```

Comment: Are you using an Express edition of Visual Studio ?

Comment: yes, Microsoft visual c++ 2010 Express

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`afxwin.h` is [MFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library) and MFC is not included in the free version of VC++ (Express Edition).

The only solution to build this application would be to pass on a Professional edition.

Answer (score 2):

Visual studio Express does not include the MFC classes.

You won't be able to build this application using Visual Studio Express.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more info for other people who stumble here from Google:

For me on my install of Visual Studio it was compiling [MFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library) just fine, then stopped all of a sudden. Turns out that my `projectname32v5.vcproj` file got currupted (this file contains, among other things, the include paths specific to this project). Restoring a previous version of this file from my version control system fixed the build.