# Building a C++ Visual Studio project in another IDE: fatal error afxwin.h

Tags: visual-studio, codeblocks, stdafx.h

I downloaded this [project's files](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2682/Serial-Communication-in-Windows) which is written in visual studio and I am trying to make it compile in Code Blocks. The issue I am having, is with the StdAfx.h/.c files, which if I understand this correctly, are used for Visual studio.

So the error is:

```
fatal error: afxwin.h: No such file or directory
```

I get this error inside AtdAfx.h file, because it tried to include it:

```
#include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components
```

If I try to delete the AtdAfx.h, my other project's files give me errors, since evey one of them uses the AtdAfx.h.

*Side note:*

This is the exact error I have [Fatal error c1083 "afxwin.h"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461701/fatal-error-c1083-afxwin-h) but he/she uses Visual studio, I use Code::Blocks.

Comment: You'll need to tell your IDE/Compiler where to find the MFC header files. Visual Studio already 'knows' by default.

Comment: Where are they in a windows 10 computer? googling "where MFC files are", there are no replies.

Comment: ... but that may be the least of your problems. Attempting to build MFC applications outside of Visual Studio/MSVC often ends badly.

Comment: Well this project uses Win32 libraries/ APIs, I cant imagine how this can end badly. 
I can already compile win32 functions/ APIs with Code::Blocks

Comment: Hmmm ... if the project isn't using MFC, then I can't see why it would `#include <afxwin.h>`. Maybe try replacing that line with `#include <Windows.h>` ... just a suggestion, as I haven't looked at the project you linked in any detail.

Comment: It seems the only reason the code is including *afxwin.h* is for the `TRACE` (and possibly `ASSERT`) macros. Neither one is required as far as functionality goes.